# Fastest way of parsing XML files for specified Tags using the Qt Framework

Tags: c++, performance, qt, xml-parsing

As far es I know there a 4 ways of parsing XML files using C++ with Qt.

```
QDom
QSax
QXMLStreamReader
QXMLQuery
```

I search in my file for a node with a specific attribute, if I've found it, I abort the parsing save the file name to a list and parse the next file. 
I accomplished that using QDom, but since i search up to 10k files with each about 400lines. it takes some time to parse them all.

My question is whether anyone of you knows about the performance of this different approaches?
Or if you have any tips to improve the performance of such a program?

I appreciate any information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, if you don't get tree structure from your xml files, use QXMLStremReader.

> QXmlStreamReader is the fastest and easiest way to read XML in Qt.
>   Because the parser works incrementally, it is particularly useful for
>   finding all occurrences of a given tag in an XML document, for reading
>   very large files that may not fit in memory, and for populating custom
>   data structures to reflect an XML document's contents.